# Binding with BasePage in Xamarin Forms

Tags: binding, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm, binding-context

I am implementing a Xamarin app with FreshMVVM framework and I want to use a BasePage to share some code among Pages.
The problem is that when I need to bind some Properties in the MainPage.xaml I have to specify the **Source** in this way to make it working: **Text="{Binding Title, Source={x:Reference mainPage}}"**. Otherwise without **Source** Binding doesn't work.
Ok, I get it but is this the right way? Is there another way to achieve the same result? What about when I have plenty of bindings in a page? For instance, is it possible "setting" the Source at un upper level, because in my opinion setting the same Source for each Binding is very annoying.

BasePage.xaml

```xaml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestXamarin.BasePage"
             x:Name="basePage">
    <ContentView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="HEADER" FontSize="Large"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference basePage}}" FontSize="Large"/>
            <ContentPresenter BindingContext="{Binding Parent.BindingContext}" 
                              Content="{Binding PageContent, Source={x:Reference basePage}}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

BasePage.xaml.cs

```html
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TestXamarin
{
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
 public partial class BasePage : ContentPage
 {
  public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
      nameof(Text),
      typeof(string),
      typeof(BasePage));

  public string Text
  {
   get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
   set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly BindableProperty PageContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
      nameof(PageContent),
      typeof(object),
      typeof(BasePage));

  public object PageContent
  {
    get { return GetValue(PageContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PageContentProperty, value); }
  }

  public BasePage()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
  }
 }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```html
<local:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestXamarin"
                x:Class="TestXamarin.MainPage"
                Text="FROM MAIN PAGE"
                x:Name="mainPage">
    <local:BasePage.PageContent>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Body" FontSize="Large"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, Source={x:Reference mainPage}}" FontSize="Large"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </local:BasePage.PageContent>
</local:BasePage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```html
public partial class MainPage : BasePage
 {
  public MainPage()
  {
   Title = "MAIN PAGE";

   InitializeComponent();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Are you using an MVVM framework? If not I would advise you to look into it because it can greatly simplify your binding experience.

Comment: Only `BindingContext` supports property value inheritance, not `Source`

Comment: @StevenThewissen Actually I am using FreshMVVM, but it seems to have same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to achieve what you are trying to do would be with control templates.

Here I have defined a template in App.xaml

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ActivityIndicatorTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter />
        <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource BlockingPanel}"
                     IsVisible="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.IsBusy}">
            <ActivityIndicator Style="{StaticResource ActivityIndicatorStyle}"
                               IsVisible="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.IsBusy}"
                               IsRunning="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.IsBusy}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Note the content presenter and the TemplateBinding.

I use it on a page like this.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.MyTestPage"
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ActivityIndicatorTemplate}"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <Grid>
    ...
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The page content replaces the content presenter in the template. Looks simpler than a base page.

Comment: Yes, what you proposed is a working solution and in fact currently I am escaping from that problem by using ControlTemplate.
What I don't like about this solution is the minor flexibility respect to the BasePage approach. As far as I know the only way to pass parameters to the ControlTemplate is Binding from the ViewModel properties, instead in some cases I would like to set parameters from the Xaml Page and with a BindableProperty I can do it.